# C# Compile source code in Command Line

Tags: c#

I have a simple "hello world" program saved in `hello.csc`.

I complied the program using this command in Command Prompt:

```
csc hello.csc
```

I needed to compile it in Command Prompt again where it will compile it to another name by keeping the same file name..

For Example: `csc hello.csc` gives me `hello.exe` and I need to get a `anotherhello.exe` file. With out renaming the `hello.csc` file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx):

```
csc /out:anotherhello.exe hello.cs
```